# Guess the number in C# with player chances

Tags: c#, .net

I made a little game, but it's not work as I wanted to. 
It is a Guess the number game. The player has 10 chances. But there is my problem. It's increase the value of playerChance until it's reach 10. What can I use instead of while?

It's output is:

```
Guess the number game! Do you wanna play? y/n
y
The game started! What is your guess?
78
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
Your number was too high!
```

Code:

```
namespace GuessTheNumberGame_v1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess the number game! Do you wanna play? y/n");
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar == 'y')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The game started! What is your guess?");
                int playerGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Random r = new Random();
                int compGuess = r.Next(1, 101);

                int playerScore = 0;
                int playerChance = 0;

                bool play = true;

                do
                {
                    while (playerChance < 10)
                    {
                        if (playerGuess > compGuess)
                        {
                            ++playerChance;
                            Console.WriteLine("Your number was too high!");
                        }
                        else if (playerGuess < compGuess)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your number was too small!");
                            ++playerChance;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ++playerScore;
                            Console.WriteLine("You win! \nYou have: " + playerScore + " points!");
                            playerChance = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Do you wanna play again? y/n");
                    if (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar == 'n')
                        play = false;
                } while (play);     
            }

            else
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you win set the  `playerChance = 11;`

Comment: Perhaps you want to iterate while `playerChance > 0`? Also, you should be decrementing the number of chances the user has when they guess instead of incrementing.

Comment: That looks like a great game but maybe this question fits more to [Stack Overflow Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would start with moving every responsibility to other methods first. After that you can try to separate it into class(es). That way the logic of what you're trying to do will become more apparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have four problems.

The first is that you don't break out of the inner loop when you're done:

```
                    else
                    {
                        ++playerScore;
                        Console.WriteLine("You win! \nYou have: " + playerScore + " points!");
                        playerChance = 0;
                        break; // <-- "breaks out" of the innermost loop early
                    }
```

A `break` is an *unconditional loop exit*.  Compare with `continue`, which *restarts* the loop and re-checks the loop condition.

The second is that the "input the user's guess" logic needs to be *inside* the inner loop!

The third is that your code crashes if the user inputs something other than a number.  Use `int.TryParse`, and if the user's input is not a number, then make them try again. You'll need a loop for that too!

The fourth is that you have no "you lose" message. Can you see how to implement that?

Finally: your problem will get easier to solve if you start breaking up your program into smaller methods. Suppose we have a method:

```
// Asks the user to guess; returns true if the user guessed correctly.
private static bool Guess(int answer)
{
  int playerGuess = GetIntegerFromUser("What is your guess?");
  // TODO: write GetIntegerFromUser
  if (playerGuess > answer)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Your number was too high!");
    return false;
  }
  else if (playerGuess < answer)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Your number was too small!");
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("You win!");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now your "main" loop gets *much easier to read*.

```
while (playerChance < 10)
{
  if (Guess(compGuess))
  {
     // TODO: Deal with winning
  }
  ...
```

and so on.  **Identify small problems, solve each with a method, and then put those solutions together**.

Comment: Using break would be my suggestion as well. I would also change the while loop to just while(true) and add a check inside the loop for playerChance==10 and output the appropriate message and do a break. It keeps the logic of checking for max tries, displaying the message, and exiting the loop all together. The outer loop already sets playerChance=0 so it doesn't need to be set in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, the reason it isn't working as expected is because you are only reading the number input once.  You will need to get a new guess each time there is an incorrect answer.

There are a few other items that will need to be addressed:

- What will happen when they get the correct answer before the 10th
  try?
- What will the user see when they lose?
- Will they get the correct prompts when they play another game?

Other suggestions I have for you for general development:

- When reading a value, don't assume it will be the correct type
- Consider creating small functions for specific tasks.  This will help you in the future with testing, updating, troubleshooting, and maintenance.  In this case, perhaps a a function to check the answer will simplify some of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (playerChance < 10)
```

To

```
while (playerChance < 10 && playerGuess != compGuess)
```

And you have to input a new guess on each iteration, so move the

```
int playerGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

To inside that loop

```
int playerGuess = -1;
...
while (playerChance < 10 && playerGuess != compGuess) {
    playerGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```